# Swift and Parse - PFQueryTableViewController loadingViewEnabled

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle, parseui

Good day! I'm using Parse for my swift project, Specifically the `PFQueryTableViewController` but i want to change the loading view when i open the app. It doesn't look good in my background so i want to change its color and shadow. Also its `UIActivityIndicatorView`. Is it possible to change this things? Here is the Screenshot for it.
[image]

I tried searching for that method in ParseUI framework but i can't find it. I hope you can help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the table controller is unique to Parse.  The spinner is just a regular UI element.  Thus, the iOS developer references are good places to look for this.

Try [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/) for the activity spinner:

[This link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html) shows information about the controller, which shows that it simply inherits from UITableViewController, and the cells/background can be styled accordingly.

In general, Parse tries to prefix its objects with PF.